# Drawing a line in librocket (html)

Tags: html, css, librocket

I want to draw a line from arbitrary position A to arbitrary position B(the line can be diagonal), it doesn't matter if the line has fixed width, it doesn't matter if images are required for it to work.

I have literally no idea how could I accomplish this.

This is required for a node graph editor in my game editor's GUI.

I am limited to the usage of the C++ libRocket API.(CSS + HTML + scripting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Render the line into an image (bitmap), then place the image on the page inside a transparent floating div.